# Possible to upgrade TFS 2008 database to existing TFS2010?

Tags: tfs, upgrade, tfs-migration

There are a lot of questions about upgrading here, but I have another, very specific one, that I don't see asked.

When installing TFS 2010, on the first run, you get a wizard, which lets you choose a database (which you presumably backed up, and restored onto the new instance) to use, and it allows you to upgrade that instance in-place.

If I'm performing a dry-run, during the course of which I do not want to disable access to the OLD tfs, is it possible for me to do this upgrade a second time without reinstalling TFS?

IE: can I create a new team project collection and point it to a tfs 2008 database and have it upgrade that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think it is possible to point to a TFS 2008 database from TFS 2010.

We have migrated our TFS 2005/2008 too.
We installed a fresh new TFS 2010 and migrated the old projects into the new TFS 2010.

All files of the projects in TFS2005/2008 are set to read only, workitem history and changesets are migrated into the new TFS2010.

We decide to switch the process template too so we created another team project with the Scrum Template.
Afterwards the source and all needed files are copied to the new Scrum team project.

Now if I let me show the history of a item under source control, it shows the history till the beginning of each item (points to the "old"/first migrated team project in TFS 2010).

Comment: Well, that's how the upgrade works, if you do a migration upgrade and restore your existing tfs databases onto a new server, you then point to the new DB using the Wizard that is run when TFS2010 first starts. I'm just curious if this ability is available later.

Answer (score 0):

I did it an upgrade test on a dummy machine and when i get to the real thing I had to uninstall and remove all leftover db's (tfs_configuration) you can see [migrate data from TFS 2008 to an already working TFS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972422/migrate-data-from-tfs-2008-to-an-already-working-tfs-2012?rq=1)